# Ionic InAppBrowser not working

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

how to open external link from a ng-repeat.
I already tried different combinations but not external window opens.
when I put just one link it works but when I use expressions {{event.lermais}} to open links does not work.

this is my code:

```
 <ion-item class="item-text-wrap item-icon-right" ng-repeat="event in events.data.results">       
 <a href="{{event.lermais}}" on-click="openLink('{{event.lermais}}', '_blank', 'location=yes'); return false;"><img ng-src="{{ event.imagens }}"></a>    
 <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
 </ion-item>
```

I'm using Android

Comment: You tried this? var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');

Comment: I need to use {{event.lermais}} because is more than one link.

Comment: `on-click="openLink(event.lermais, '_blank', 'location=yes');` make this change

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
ng-click ="openLink(event.lermais)"
```

Controller

```
$scope.openLink= function(url){ 
     window.open(url, "_blank", "location=yes");
}
```

Its a cakewalk.

Comment: Not working, only works if I put it this way (www.google.com), I dont know what to do more.

Comment: Can you exactly post what you get in "event.lermais" ... Just JSON.stringify(event.lermais) and post it in comment.

Comment: I´m getting the window opening in the system window and not into external window. sorry my english

Comment: From here {{event.lermais}} I´m getting   text and images from a $http service.

Comment: {{event.lermais}} should be a url. I guess its not a url.

Comment: The {{event.lermais}}  is the result of all url and it is working when I click  opens a new window with the full article within the system window but should open an external window. So tell me how do you open a list of urls using inAppBrowser plugin?

Comment: I cant help unless you post what exactly is in {{event.lemais}}. Just console.log() it. and Post it here. Why are you being so secretive. :)

Comment: I'm not posting because the content is too big, but here the content this is the result from {{ event.lermais}}:  lermais: "http://dioguinho.pt/sofia-ribeiro-reage-ao-assunto-polemica-sobre-a-sua-mae/", imagens: "http://dioguinho.pt/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/mae-sofia-ribeiro-300x160.jpg"    0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object
6: Object
7: Object
8: Object
9: Object
10: Object
11: Object
12: Object
13: Object
14: Object

Answer (score 0):

you can do that bu using following eg-

```
<a href="{{menu.url}}" onclick="window.open(this.href,'_self');">
    {{menu.title}}
</a>
```

this might work for you.